# iTunes syncs the same handful of songs on every sync

Tags: itunes, sync, ipod, ipod-touch

Every time I sync my iPod (Touch 2G), there are about 20 or 30 songs that iTunes insists on syncing. I usually sync just to get a couple of updated podcasts, but have to wait while it needlessly syncs the songs. The songs themselves seem to be fine, as I've listened to some just before it thought they needed to be synced. Nothing is changing on the files themselves - I haven't been updating any tags or album art or anything. Any idea why it thinks these same songs need to be synced every time, and how I can tell it otherwise?

Comment: I was able to resolve this by converting the ID3 tags to 2.3. This is possible from Music.app (née iTunes) by selecting the file(s) and choosing *File > Convert > Convert ID3 Tags... > ID3 tag version > v2.3*. This might mess up certain parts of your tags so it might be wise to backup beforehand. In my case, though, everything was fine.

Source and further tips: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254531758?answerId=258471617022#258471617022

PS: I wasn't able to post an answer because of my reputation.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254531758?answerId=258471617022#258471617022

Comment: Additional insight: It was a little bit hard to figure out which songs have problems syncing so I just took a lot of screenshots via `command + shift + 3` while the sync process showed them. I then found the songs from the screenshots, put them all in a playlist and ran the ID3 tag conversion on them all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all good responses, but the problem seemed to clear itself up - it hasn't behaved this way in quite some time. I'll chalk it up to iTunes upgrades or something, but I didn't want to leave this question hanging out without a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

If you played a song once on your iPod and three times on your computer since the last sync the data related to that file is going to be different. iTunes will then update the play count information on both your iPod and computer with the correct information (add 3 plays to the iPod, 1 play to the computer).  This doesn't mean it's updating the song file itself, just the database information related to that file.

Comment: I did not know that. However, some of the songs have not been played on the iPod or the computer for a while. (One is a Police album I haven't listened to in a long time.)

Comment: If it started to play once but you hit next, that adds to the 'skip count'. iTunes keeps track of all kinds of data related to your music. All of it is accessible in iTunes itself. If it's doing chunks of the exact same songs every single sync something else is the problem. In that case I'd recommend resetting your iPod to factory settings and resyncing it to your iTunes library.

Comment: You have no idea how many times I've resynced. I've got an unrelated problem where the library gets corrupted on a sync and I have to reset and start over. This "handful of songs" problem seems to persist even after a full resync.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it is a problem with the album artwork for those tracks.  You will need to manually unassign the album artwork for each track, then re-get the album art.

Answer (score 0):

When your device is plugged in and iTunes is running, click on your device in the left column. From there you can see all of your sync settings. You can turn all syncing off except for podcasts, for example.

Comment: I suppose, but I'd like to know what's wrong with those specific files that's fooling iTunes. The next time I purchase a song or update a tag, it's going to re-sync those songs when I turn music syncing back on.